# Поместить значение из localStorage в tbody

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Я помещаю в localStorage таблицу:

```
localStorage.setItem('table', tbody);
```

Условно ее innerHTML выглядит вот таким образом:

```
    <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>
    <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>
```

Я хочу чтобы при перезагрузке tbody присваивалось значение из localStorage.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');

tbody.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('table');

...

localStorage.setItem('table', tbody.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я писал localStorage.setItem ( 'table', tbody ), а затем писал tbody.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('table').innerHTML и это не срабатывало. Не подскажете почему ? 
Просто мне кажется, что это то же самое

Comment: @shadow1337 Потому что в `localStorage` сохраняются *строки*, а у них нет свойства `innerHTML`.